# How can I reconnect to a ssh session after a broken pipe?

Tags: ssh, openssh

So I was running `apt-get upgrade` on a server when the router decided it had been too long since it last made me angry: It dropped all connection. Moral of the story is to use `screen` a lot when you're on a bum router.

Anyway, I logged back in and found in htop that the process was still hanging there, still waiting for my Y/n to upgrade (hadn't hit it yet, luckily). Is there any way I can reattach to a session that had been broken off? I ended up just killing it since it wasn't in the middle of package management but it would be great to know for future reference.

Comment: I'm surprised the `apt-get` process was still running.  It should have died along with the whole process chain up to SSH.  I've noticed that `do-dist-upgrade` automatically starts in a `screen`/`byobu` session: maybe in some circumstances, `apt-get` does the same?

Comment: I had an `apt upgrade` running waiting for input while my ssh session broke. After reconnecting I killed the running apt process and then continued from last upgrade step with `dpkg --configure -a` - which should complete all pending packages.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The answer to your proper question is: **you can't**. I think the main problem is that the authentication procedures will be out of sync. It Just Doesn't Work Like That.

As you have yourself noticed, the solution is to use screen when possible (by the way, [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/) is an alternative to screen).

Comment: But what if you have passwordless ssh? Can you do it then?

Comment: `byobu` is a nice, easier to use front end to `screen` (or `tmux`) - definitely worth a look (:

Comment: Sridhar-Samobol, authentication still needs to take place. Attaching to a running session has no way to do the initial handshake again, so it's invariants would be broken if we introduced a new session into an existing one. Answer: no.

Comment: For an actual answer see @tanius' `reptyr` reply.

Answer (score 33):

While you can't reattach to a broken SSH session, **you can reparent the process running inside SSH** – functionally equivalent to what you want.

### Instructions

In your case, you would take over the `apt-get` process, with the goal to control it from a *new* SSH session, `screen` session or the like. My favourite for this is the `reptyr` command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install reptyr
$ ps ax | grep apt-get
10626 pts/8   R+     0:32 apt-get upgrade
```

Then, with the pid you found for your process:

```
$ sudo reptyr -T 10626
```

Or if that does not work, try:

```
$ reptyr 10626
```

After this stage, all your keyboard input goes to the program you took over. Unfortunately you will not see old output of the SSH session, such as the `apt-get` output asking you for confirmation.

### Explanations

There are multiple other tools that basically work the same as `reptyr` (that is, via `ptrace` debug attachment). See the following questions and answers where they are discussed:

- [How can I disown a running process and associate it to a new screen shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4034)
- [Resume command running in dropped SSH session](https://serverfault.com/q/115998)

In the instructions above, the `reptyr 10626` uses `ptrace` debug attachment while the `sudo reptyr -T 10626` command uses TTY stealing and is preferable ([details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/280369)).

Finally, the reason why you can't take over a SSH session this way is because a `sshd` process is not controlled by a host terminal, instead it *provides* the slave part of a terminal – a `pts` device – while the master part controlling it resides on the client machine, here with a broken-down SSH session in between. When you force taking over such a `sshd` process with `reptyr -s <pid>`, your keyboard input goes to that process, not its active child process. So a "Ctrl+Z" will simply kill off that `sshd`.

Comment: Can you explain how you can install `reptyr` using `apt-get` in order to connect to an `apt-get` process that is still running? Doesn't the running process lock `dpkg` to prevent `reptyr` from being installed?

Comment: @MikeAllen Good point. I believe I used it to attach to a process that was not `apt-get` but then wrote the answer for this specific question without noticing the point you raised.

Comment: Note that if you attach your process this way and you get disconnected AGAIN, then you have to find the still running reptyr PID to re-attach, not the original PID. If you try to attach to original PID while reptyr is still running you'll get "Unable to find the fd for the pty!" message.

Comment: @MikeAllen if you don't have reptyr installed and you're trying to recover from a situation where dpkg is locked (thereby preventing you from running `apt-get` or `aptitude`) you can upload (via `sftp`, `scp`,  etc.) `/usr/bin/reptyr` from a compatible system and then use that binary the way @tanius describes.  I.E. if you upload it to your home directory, run it via `sudo ./reptyr -T ...`. (Afterwards you can install reptyr normally if you'd like.)

Answer (score 9):

For running long lasting processes, I use **screen**, or **byobu** if you want a more friendly interface.

For screen, you can use:

```
screen [program] [args]
```

This will run [program] and its [args] inside a **screen** session. Once the program is finished, the session is automatically closed. If you wish to keep the session after your program runs, just run **screen** without any arguments and a new prompt will appear inside the session. **CTRL+A+D** detaches the terminal from the current session.

To re-attach to a previous session:

```
screen -r
```

If there is only one session open, it will reattach immediately. If multiple sessions are ongoing, it will ask you which one you want to attach to. If you know the session name, you can just add it as an argument to this command line.

**Byobu** is a nice improvement. It's based on **screen**, but provides a bar at the bottom that shows all current sessions as tabs and gives easier shortcuts to move around those. You can:

- F2 start a new session
- F3 move to the next session tab on the left
- F4 move to the next session tab on the right
- F8 give a friendly name to the current session tab
- F9 opens a options menu
- CTRL+A+D detaches all sessions from the terminal.

**WORD OF ADVICE**: avoid leaving a session opened with the user **root**. If anyone gains access to your terminal (locally or remotely), they can easily re-attach to an ongoing session and use your system as root. If needed, it's best to start a session using a common user and *sudo* indivudual command lines as necessary.

Comment: May I quote the OP: "Moral of the story is to **use screen** a lot". Apparently that was not the question here.

Comment: Thanks for the writeup but January was correct.

Comment: Use sudo screen <command> to setup a screen as root, which needs sudo access to reconnect to it.

Far better than starting a screen normally, then changing to root within it.

Answer (score 3):

I was doing `do-dist-upgrade` via ssh from a laptop which went into suspend, hence `Broken pipe`. Upon going back into the machine I was seeing the upgrade-related processes still running, among which a `whiptail` asking me for input (which display manager to choose) and, relevantly, a root-owned `SCREEN`. I was able to do `sudo su -` and `screen -r` to attach to the session and, lo and behold, I have the whiptail dialog in front of me able to take input. I was able to resume the upgrade seamlessly.

Note: this was an upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.